# Laravel Queue Cache not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I have used Laravel queues in my application and when i try to run

```
 php artisan queue:restart
```

it gives me following exception:

```
 ErrorException  : file_put_contents(/storage/framework/cache/data/ee/2f/ee2f842aa7bb1f53edf3a2ed2c09a1807ffa6c90): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at /var/www/html/asd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122
    118|      * @return int
    119|      */
    120|     public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    121|     {
  > 122|         return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
    123|     }
    124|
    125|     /**
    126|      * Prepend to a file.

  Exception trace:

  1   file_put_contents("/var/www/html/asd/storage/framework/cache/data/ee/2f/ee2f842aa7bb1f53edf3a2ed2c09a1807ffa6c90", "9999999999i:1558912298;")
      /var/www/html/asd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122

  2   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::put("/var/www/html/asd/storage/framework/cache/data/ee/2f/ee2f842aa7bb1f53edf3a2ed2c09a1807ffa6c90", "9999999999i:1558912298;")
      /var/www/html/asd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php:65

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I have tried running following commands but to no avail:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

I am not able to reflect changes made to my application logic that is in queue handlers, any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to run `php artisan config:cache` with the other commands

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere else that you could try

`chmod 775 -R storage`